# UITapGestureRecognizer works first time, but not second time

Tags: swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

[Greatly simplified]

I'm following a "Let's Build That App" YouTube series on Firebase 3. It's from 2016, so I've had to rework some of the code since Swift has evolved since then, but mostly it's a useful tutorial.

But, I'm stuck on something.

[image]

The red box is intended to be a custom `titleView` with an Image and Name, but I've simplified it to try to find the problem.

`viewWillAppear` calls `setupNavbar` which sets up the `navbar.titleView`:

```
func setupNavbar() {
  let titleView = UIView()
  titleView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 40)
  titleView.backgroundColor = .red

  let containerView = UIView() // for the Image and Label, later

  containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
  containerView.backgroundColor = .green

  // left, top, width, height anchors equal to same for titleView
  containerView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleView.leftAnchor)
  // top, width, height are similar

  titleView.addSubview(containerView)

  self.navigationItem.titleView = titleView

  let recognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(showChatController))
  titleView.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
}
```

The selector's function is:

```
@objc func showChatController() {
  let chatController = ChatLogTableViewController()
  navigationController?.pushViewController(chatController, animated: true)
}
```

The class `ChatLogTableViewController` has just the default `viewDidLoad()`.

First, I'm surprised the box is red, and not green. Why is that?

Second, if I click the red box, the ChatController is loaded, as expected. But, when I click "Back" and return to this screen, the red box is not visible, thus I can no longer tap on it. BUT....If I sign out and sign in/up again, the box is red and I can click it again.

What am I missing?

Update 1: The "+" creates a new controller and presents it.

```
present(UINavigationController(
  rootViewController: NewMessageTableViewController()), 
  animated: true, 
  completion: nil)
```

That controller is currently empty, except for a `leftBarButtonItem` which is just a barButtonSystemItem (.cancel). Just like "Sign Out", this also "resets" the gesture and it works.

Update 2: Code added upon request.

Update 3: question greatly simplified. Also, if I change the `showChatController` code to just `print ("show Chat Controller")`, I can click to my heart's content; the red box and its tap gesture both remain.

So, there is something happening when I `...pushViewController` and then come back.

Comment: can you share your code when the back button is pressed?

Comment: There is no code. The `ChatLogTableViewController` only has `viewDidLoad` which does nothing but set the `navigation.Title`

Comment: can you show your `titleView` code? `self.navigationItem.titleView = titleView
titleView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(showChatController)))` and where have you placed this code in `ViewDidload` or `ViewWillAppear`?

Comment: @HabinLama code added. It's called from `viewWillAppear`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set `isUserInteractionEnabled` property of the label which you set as the navBar's `titleView`? I know it's silly but I've missed this a lot of times :)

```
let recognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(YourViewController.titleWasTapped))
titleView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
titleView.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
```

Comment: I just tried it, but it didn't change anything. Which is not surprising, since the *first* tap work, just not the second.

Answer (score 0):

```
you can try following things:
1. "User Interaction Enabled" in the UILabel Attributes Inspector in the Storyboard.

2. override func viewDidLoad(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    self.titleView.userInteractionEnabled = true
    var tapGesture = titleView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(showChatController)))

        self.titleView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    }

    func showChatController() {
        println("Tap Gesture recognized")
    }
```

Comment: 1. Not using Storyboard. 2. The code to create the views, their constraints and add the tap gesture is in a separate function which is called from viewWillAppear. Using the debugger, I can confirm that it's called when the VC is first created and any time I come back to this VC. I've also confirmed that, for all but the first time, the `self.navigationItem.titleView` is not nil and has the views and gestures that were created previously.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Zonker I've tested your `setupNavBar()`. It's working fine nothing worng with your code when I press and go back clicking **titleView**. Reason why you're not getting **.green** color is you have to give height and width for **containerView** and big reason is you've put **addSubView** code below the **anchor** and there is no `.isActive = true` in your `containerView.leftAnchor.constraint...` Please check `setupNavBar()` code below:

```
func setupNavbar() {
    let titleView = UIView()
    titleView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 40)
    titleView.backgroundColor = .red

    let containerView = UIView() // for the Image and Label, later

    containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    containerView.backgroundColor = .green
    titleView.addSubview(containerView)
    // left, top, width, height anchors equal to same for titleView
    containerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300).isActive = true
    containerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
    containerView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    // top, width, height are similar

    self.navigationItem.titleView = titleView

    let recognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(showChatController))
    titleView.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
}
```

It would better if you push your code in github so we can test your code

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I made a mistake copying my code as I *do* have the ".isActive = true" for all my constraints.

Comment: Okey no problem.

Comment: Also, I have all four constraints for `containerView`, I just didn't want to type them all in, since they are identical except for `left`, `top`, 'width`, and `height`